# Going back to previous page while clicking Submit button in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic

I have this code written in classic ASP. I want to make it go to previous page when submit button is clicked and chosen drop-down value is submitted. I know I can go to the previous page when I use `Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")`, but How to implement this in following code, how to make it work when Submit button is clicked it goes to previous page getting value from variable "PreviousPage" that is being used in code like below:

../Example.asp:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<% Option Explicit %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Project Site</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/fnureports.css" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">

</style>
</head>

<!--#include file="../sqlConnection.asp" -->
    <!--#include file="../sqlConnection1.asp" -->   
         <%
Dim YearID
Dim SeasonID
Dim myStudentID
          YearID = Request.Form("dYear")
          SeasonID = Request.Form("dSeason")

If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD")= "POST" Then
          myID = Request.QueryString("uniqueid")
          Updatedate myID, YearID, SeasonID
  End If
         %>

<body>
<div align = "center">
    <div>
    <form id="form1" method="post" action="Example.asp<%= request.querystring %>">

    <select class="dropYear" name="dYear">
    <option value="select">2014</option>
    <option value="2015">2015</option>
     </select>

    &nbsp &nbsp &nbsp;

    <select class="dropSeason" name="dSeason">
    <option value="select">FALL</option>
    <option value="Winter">WINTER</option>
       </select>

    <br /><br />

   <%
    Dim PreviousPage
    PreviousPage = Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER")
    Response.Write PreviousPage
    %>

     <ul class="buttons">
     <input id="save" method="post" class="btTxt" type="submit" value="Submit"; />

     </ul> 
     </form>
    </div>
    <br/>
      </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Any idea on this one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: Previous answer was dumb, the referrer is going to be the current page because it is a POST.  You need to store the referrer somewhere before you hit submit; the easiest place would probably be on the query string (but a hidden field would also work).

```
<form id="form1" method="post" action="Example.asp<%= request.querystring %>&goBackTo=<% =Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER") %>">
```

then

```
If Request.ServerVariables("REQUEST_METHOD")= "POST" Then
    myID = Request.QueryString("uniqueid")
    Updatedate myID, YearID, SeasonID
    Response.Redirect Request.QueryString("goBackTo")
End If
```

Comment: I used this code: Response.Redirect Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_REFERER") as you asked inside If conditional statement. It's not redirecting me to previous page after I hit Submit button.

Comment: I tried edited code way also, it doesn't take me to previous page.

Comment: Debug. See what the querystring contains. `Response.write(Request.Querystring)`

Comment: It doesn't work because the referer is a URL in its own right so it needs to be escaped using `Server.UrlEncode()`.

Comment: Would also be easier to manage placing the Referer URL in a `<input type="hidden" name="goBackTo" />` and removing the querystring from the `<form>` action. That way you can call `Request.Form("goBackTo")`. A lot cleaner and doesn't require `Server.UrlEncode()`.

Comment: @Lankymart: Can you please show me an example how to implement. Sorry I got confused as I am using this HTTP_REFERER first time. where to implement this feature  <input type="hidden" name="goBackTo"/> in my code?

Comment: Code Worked using "HTTP_REFERER" to go back to previous page. I have updated mine code above with the working one.

Comment: You shouldn't update the question with the solution.  If you've found an solution that works you should create an answer with the working code if there is no answer that already has the solution.  Otherwise people can't easily see what the problem was and what the solution to that is.  If another answer on the question helped you achieve the solution but wasn't quite right, give them an upvote and mention them in your answer. I've rollbacked the question